How to shrink a polygon vertices to find Net floor area
I am workin on a project in c# of modeling building for greenBuilding.
for the simulation, I need to put the vertices for the outside of the flat external wall, the the centeral of the wall between flats.
For this, I am doing great and I also calculated the area.
But I also need the NET floor area by reducing the walls thickness.
Not all the wall have the same thickness but I do know this

the Gross area

the thickness of each wall

the length of each wall


How can I substract the walls from the Gross to get the NET floor area

Calculate the area of the wall and then subtract that from the floor size. Length times thickness are the wall area.

You will need to subtract the area occupied by walls from the gross area.
However this risks double-counting the corners as being in 2 walls, so you will need to add the corner back
Net area = Gross area - Wall(s) Area + Corner(s) Area

In order to calculate the corner area, you will need more information, such as  which walls meet and whether they are always at right angles
